# How to update values in a list, using a foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, foreach

I have some values stored on a database, that I am query'ing.

So for each object, I want to save the value to my list.

Currently I'm doing it, in a function that I call once pr second, like this:

```
foreach (var obj in results)
{   
    MyList.Add (ValueSavedOnDatabase);

}
```

But my issue is that, if I have, for example, 20 objects on the database, then this function will save the values in the first 20 indexes in the list.
Then each time the function gets called (once per second), it will add 20 new indexes to the list, instead of just overwriting the 20 indexes, which I need it to. 
So after 3 seconds, I currently get 60 indexes in this list (When I just wanted 20).

Does anyone have an advice, for how I can achieve this overwriting, of these indexes in the list, instead of continouing creating new indexes ?

I'm using Unity and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to empty your list before the loop:

```
MyList.Clear(); // Clear the list

foreach (var obj in results) { // do whatever you need
   MyList.Add (ValueSavedOnDatabase);
}
```

---

Or if the size of the list is always the same per each call, you can do this:

```
 int i = 0;
 foreach (var obj in results) { 
   MyList[i] = ValueSavedOnDatabase;
   i++;
}
```

**N.B.** I only suggest this last, in case you are using an `ArrayList`.